# Centering footer menu

Tags: html, css

Here is a preview of some coding http://jsfiddle.net/joelupet/9NKzU/.

I would like to see my menu centered. Also, if there is alternative way like add id$class to UL elements structure.

What to do?

Comment: Small advice : add more tags to the topic ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this! Here's what I'd recommend.

Change your CSS to the following:

```
#footer_menu {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color:red;
}

#footer_menu ul{
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden;    
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/dwpmd/) for an example implementation.